# error: type mismatch::found :Boolean:: required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column issue::Spark/Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 Dataframes in spark Df1 and Df2 i am joining these 2 Dataframes based on one common column i.e. Id ,and then added one extra column result and checking 
multiple column with or condition if any of column data matched then i need to insert in new column as matched and if no condition matched then need to pass as 'Not Matched' in that column. I am writing below code.

```
    df1.join(df2,df1("id") === df2("id"))
    .withColumn("Result",when(df1("adhar_no") === df2("adhar_no") || 
    when(df1("pan_no") === df2("pan_no") || 
    when(df1("Voter_id") === df2("Voter_id") ||  
    when(df1("DL_no") === df2("DL_no"),"Matched"))))
   .otherwise("Not Matched"))
```

But getting  below error  message.

```
    error: type mismatch;
    found   : Boolean
    required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

can anyone Please give me a hint how should  i write my query to generate desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
df1.join(df2,df1("id") === df2("id"))
    .withColumn("Result",
    when((
            df1("adhar_no") === df2("adhar_no") || 
            df1("pan_no") === df2("pan_no") || 
            df1("Voter_id") === df2("Voter_id") ||  
            df1("DL_no") === df2("DL_no")
        ),"Matched"
    ).otherwise("Not Matched")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove these `when` statements:

```
  df.join(df,df("id") === df("id"))
    .withColumn("Result",
      when(
        df("adhar_no") === df("adhar_no") || 
        df("pan_no") === df("pan_no") || 
        df("Voter_id") === df("Voter_id") || 
        df("DL_no") === df("DL_no"),"Matched"
      ).otherwise("Not Matched"))
```

Comment: Thanks @chlebek ..yes it worked for me actually i was also using drop method in my code and  at one place used drop method for df("pan_no")  so was getting error.